# Javascript multiple email regexp validation

Tags: javascript, regex, email, email-validation

Normally validation of simple email is:

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/
```

This will validate email like `test@test.com`

But how to validate if email is multiple?

```
entry 1: test@test.com, test1@test.com, test2@test.com
entry 2: test@test.com , test1@test.com , test2@test.com
entry 3: test@test.com, test1@test.com , test2@test.com
entry 4: test@test.com
```

This emails is a possible entries that user will input. Also expect thier is 2 or 3 or 4 or more emails sometimes.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Split the emails on a comma and validate the entries

```
var x = getEmails();
var emails = x.split(",");
emails.forEach(function (email) {
  validate(email.trim());
});
```

Where getEmails() gets the emails from the page, and validate runs your regex against the emails

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
    function validateEmails(string) {
        var regex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var result = string.replace(/\s/g, "").split(/,|;/);        
        for(var i = 0;i < result.length;i++) {
            if(!regex.test(result[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }       
        return true;
    }
```

accept both comma and semicolon as separator

Answer (score 4):

Here is a regex for multiple mail validation without split

```
function validateMultipleEmails(string) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)+([;]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+))*$/;
    return regex.test(string);
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/TUXLED/1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to split the entry by commas, and then test the individual email subentries against the regexp.

```
var valid = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var entries = entry.split(",");

if(valid.test(entries[0]))...    //or however your testing against the regex
```

You might also want to trim any whitespace before testing any of the stripped email substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for jquery validation:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("multiemail", function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    var emails = value.split(','),
        valid = true;
    for (var i = 0, limit = emails.length; i < limit; i++) {
        value = emails[i];
        valid = valid && jQuery.validator.methods.email.call(this, value, element);
    }
    return valid;
}, "Invalid email format: please use a comma to separate multiple email addresses.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateEmail(emailAddress) {
  var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return emailPattern.test(emailAddress);
}

function validate() {
  $("#result").text("");
  var email = $("#emailAddress").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#result").text(email + " validation successful");
    $("#result").css("color", "white");
  } else {
    $("#result").text(email + " validation failed");
    $("#result").css("color", "red");
  }
  return false;
}

$("form").bind("submit", validate);
```

```css
.divSection{
  text-align: center; padding: 8%;
  }
.pSection{
  border: none;    color: white;    padding: 10px 100px;    text-align: center;    text-decoration: none;    display: inline-block;    font-size: 24px;    margin: 3% 0%;    border-radius: 6px;    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;   transition-duration: 0.4s;    font-family: Roboto-Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color: #4184f3; margin: auto;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divSection">
<form action="dashboard/user/profile" method="POST">
  <input id="emailAddress" placeholder="Enter Email" value="shubham20.yeole@gmail.com">
  <input type='submit' value="check">
</form>
  </div>

<div class="divSection" >
<p class="pSection" id='result'></p>
</div>
```

This is javascript code to check if email contains more than one @ characters

```
var count=0;
email = "shubham20.ye@ole@gmail.com";
alert(email);
for(i =0; i<email.length;i++){
if(email.charAt(i) == "@"){
count++;
}}
if(count>1){
   alert("not ok")
} else {
    alert("ok")
}
```

Alternate way is by using the standard pattern of the email

```
var pattern= /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
re.test(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript multiple email regexp validation in ruby dynamic data

```
  <span id="error_message_<%= item.id %>" class="p-3 mb-2 text-danger text-center">Multiple emails must be separated by comma.</span>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, style: 'width: 60%;', required: true, id: "emails_#{item.id}", placeholder: "Multiple emails must be separated by comma." %>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    document.getElementById("cc_submit_<%= item.id %>").disabled = true;

    document.getElementById('error_message_<%= item.id %>').style.display='none';

  });

  $('#emails_<%= item.id %>').keyup( function() {

    var emails = $('#emails_<%= item.id %>').val();
    var emails = emails.split(",");
    var valid = true;
    var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var invalidEmails = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < emails.length; i++) {
      emails[i] = emails[i].trim();
      if( emails[i] == "" || ! regex.test(emails[i])){
        invalidEmails.push(emails[i]);
      }
    }

    if(invalidEmails != 0) {

      document.getElementById("cc_submit_<%= item.id %>").disabled = true;

      document.getElementById("error_message_<%= item.id %>").style.display='block';

      }
    else{

      document.getElementById("cc_submit_<%= item.id %>").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('error_message_<%= item.id %>').style.display='none';

    }
  })
```